# Extracting blocks/ROIs from Eigen::SparseMatrix without copying

Tags: c++, copy, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

I wonder is there any good way to extract blocks/ROIs from Eigen::SparseMatrix?
More precisely, what I want to extract is **inner vectors**.

What I want to do is like:

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,Eigen::RowMajor> SpMat;
// Prepare some sparse matrix
SpMat spmat;
// Extract lines from it
const SpMat& row_i = spmat.innerVector(i);
const SpMat& row_j = spmat.innerVector(j);
// Some calculation with row_i and row_j...
```

As I tested, the data of `row_i` and `row_j` is **copied (!!)** from `spmat`.
However, obviously, it is inefficient.
The data (esp. `row_i.m_data.m_values` & `row_i.m_data.m_indices`) of inner vectors is continuous part of original data (`spmat.m_data.m_values` & `spmat.m_data.m_indices` resp.), so there should be smarter way.

I may be able to implement new method to do this, but it require me a tough digging into the source code. So I don't want to.

Any help is grateful!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use the c++11 `auto` keyword to declare `row_i`and `row_j` as true read-write expressions, or use the proper type:

```
const auto row_i = spmap.innerVector(i); // C++11 version
const SpMat::InnerVectorReturnType row_i = spmap.innerVector(i); // C++98 version
```

Moreover, not that by default a SparseMatrix is stored in column major, therefore an "inner-vector" is a column. If you want to reference rows, then you have to use a row-major storage layout:

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,RowMajor> SpMat;
```

Comment: It works as I expected! Thxs:) And also thanks for pointing out about column/row-major. I modified my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [`MappedSparseMatrix`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MappedSparseMatrix.html) class. It wraps an existing set of data and associated parameters (I think, I've never used it). I assume it works similarly to the [`Eigen::Map`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) class but I may be wrong.

```
MappedSparseMatrix<double> mat(int rows, int cols, int nnz,
                    int* outerIndexPtr, int* innerIndexPtr,
                    Scalar* valuePtr);
```

[Source](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=86163)

Comment: Thanks, it also solves my problem. I can do like `Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix<double> row_i_map(1, spmat.innerSize(), nnz, spmat.outerIndexPtr()+j, spmat.innerIndexPtr(), spmat.valuePtr());
`. For later users, I point out that `MappedSparseMatrix` expect `innerIndexPtr` and `valuePtr` to be continuous on memory. This mean, you can use only with `innerVecotr(s)` and if you want extract multiple inner vectors, original matrix should be [compressd](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#a4549e80dac9fd4f4c9ecee00814ecaa5).

Comment: @ShinichiTAMURA is there a way to know how many items each of the outer, inner and values arrays will hold? If say we'd need to create a deep copy and `memcpy` these arrays, is there a way to extract these size? The CSR definition of nnz for values and innerIndex, and (n+1) for outerIndex does not seem to work properly. Link for CSR: http://www.netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node91.html

Comment: @Bar You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593085/serializing-decomposed-matrix-from-eigen-sparselu-object/24595433#24595433) to see an example of serializing s sparse matrix. Look for `outS = m.outerSize();`.

Comment: Thanks @AviGinsburg. One more question: Is the creation of a MappedSparseMatrix zero-copy, or does it involve data copying?

Comment: @Bar zero copy.