# Zero-copy construction of an Eigen SparseMatrix

Tags: c++, eigen, zero-copy

I have the following problem:

I have an `Eigen::SparseMatrix` I need to send over the network, and my network library only supports sending arrays of primitive types.

I can retrieve the pointers to the backing arrays of my SparseMatrix by doing something like (here's the [backing object's code](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/CompressedStorage_8h_source.html)):

```
// Get pointers to the indices and values, send data over the network
int num_items = sparse_matrix.nonZeros()
auto values_ptr = sparse_matrix.data().valuePtr()
auto index_ptr = sparse_matrix.data().indexPtr()

network_lib::send(values_ptr, num_items)
network_lib::send(index_ptr, 2 * num_items) // Times two b/c we have 2 indices per value
```

Now on the other side I have access to these two arrays. But AFAIK there is no way to create a SparseArray without copying all the data into a new SparseMatrix (see [docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/group__TutorialSparse.html#title3) for construction).

I'd like to do something like:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> zero_copy_matrix(num_rows, num_cols);
zero_copy_matrix.data().valuePtr() = received_values_ptr;
zero_copy_matrix.data().indexPtr() = received_index_ptr;
```

But this throws a compiler error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment zero_copy_matrix.data().valuePtr() = received_values_ptr;
```

Any idea on how we could zero-copy construct a sparse Eigen matrix from existing arrays of indexes and data?

Another approach I tried that didn't work (this is local, no communication):

```
zero_copy_matrix.reserve(num_non_zeros);
zero_copy_matrix.data().swap(original_matrix.data());
```

When I try to print out the `zero_copy_matrix` it has no values in it.

Comment: From what I understand, this is a current limitation of C++ and there are proposals for memory mapped/persistent (I don't know the right term) objects for c++20 (or later) but haven't seen any real commitment to any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around I think a good option for me would be to use an `Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>>` as such:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>> sparse_map(num_rows, num_cols, num_non_zeros,
                             original_outer_index_ptr, original_inner_index_ptr,
                             original_values_ptr);
```

AFAIK, this should be zero-copy. Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33387750/209882).

Comment: `MapppedSparseMatrix` is deprecated, better use `Map<SparseMatrix<float>>` (simple copy-paste replacement in your case).

Comment: Thanks @ggael I'll change the answer as well.