# Operations on Eigen Map sparse objects

Tags: c++, eigen

In my application I have to send `Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>` objects over the network, which means I need to serialize them and on the other end deserialize them into a `Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>>`, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51939356/209882).

My issue now is that I'd like to perform some operations on the receiving end, namely sum all matrices that arrive.

However when I try to add together two Eigen::Map objects it produces a compiler error. This is true for any operation I try to perform on an Eigen::Map:

```
// This leads to a compiler error
Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>> recon = SerializedVectorToMappedSparseMatrix(serialized_vec);
Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>> recondouble = recon * 2;
```

> error: conversion from ‘const type {aka const
>   Eigen::SparseMatrix}’ to non-scalar type
>   ‘Eigen::Map >’ requested
>   Eigen::Map> recondouble = (recon *
>   2).eval();

However this compiles and works as expected:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> recondouble = recon * 2;
```

In my network case I'd like to perform a sum of the existing and incoming Map:

```
existing_matrix += incoming_matrix;
```

This causes the compiler error:

> error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are
>   ‘Eigen::Map >’ and ‘const
>   Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp,
>   const Eigen::Map >, const
>   Eigen::Map > >’)    return
>   derived() = derived() + other.derived();

So my question is: Are we supposed to convert Eigen::Map objects to Eigen:Matrix if we are to perform operations between them? [The example in the docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html#title2) seems to suggest otherwise.

Am I doing something wrong in my use of the Eigen::Map container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Map` object is a wrapper to existing memory, allowing you to treat it as if it's actually an Eigen object with a few exceptions. Specifically, you can't change the memory, so resizing, allocating, etc. aren't allowed. In your example,

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>> recondouble = recon * 2;
```

should be changed to

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> recondouble = recon * 2;
```

(as you noted in your question) as the `operator=`/c'tor needs to allocate memory for `recondouble`. The sparse `operator+=` often needs to reallocate memory unless the rhs elements are a subset of the lhs ones. I don't know if the mapped sparse matrix disallows this operation for this reason or not (and I don't have time to look into it right now).

P.S. the example in the docs only talks about dense matrices, and therefore reallocation in `operator+=` is not relevant.

Comment: Right, the `+=` operator between sparse matrices could lead to re-allocation because of new indexes being added, hence the operation is not possible. Thanks for the explanation!